# Bottom tool bar is missing when i open the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitoolbar

**When i load the app my bottom tool bar is missing but when i move the toolbar to the center of the screen it showing .My view frame is default 0,0,320,480  .Then why bottom toolbar not appearing  ?
check the image   ,you can see the top bar but bottom bar is missing ,its not hidden in code or property  ,when i move it to top or center**strong text** of screen we can see that**

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  UIAlertView* _alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading Chapters..."
                                                             message:@"\n"
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];

        UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        // UIProgressView *loading=[[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];

        // loading.center=CGPointMake(50,100);
        spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5); // .5 so it doesn't blur

        [_alertView addSubview:spinner];
        // [_alertView addSubview:loading];

        [spinner startAnimating];
        [_alertView show];
          if(loadingProgressBar+1>[sharedManager.spineArray count]) {

            [_alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        }


    [_alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
      [super viewDidLoad];

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))

    {
        webView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,480,315);

          BottomBar.frame=CGRectMake(0,260, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds),41);

        //NSLog(@"%f%f",CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds));

    }
    }
```

Comment: can you add some then we can understand your issue. how are you adding toolbar using custom code or from xib?

Comment: from xib ,check updated codes

Comment: check your struts or auto layout constraints of the bottom toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that your toolbar view property is something like this

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881453/refresh-uiwebview-without-any-shaking

Comment: Please consider my above question

Comment: ok .. Anoop Vaidhy is best person for checking  your question