# Refresh UIwebview without any shaking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, reload

Currently iam refreshing webview using the following code

```
[webview reload];
```

but **in this case when i open that viewcontroller i can see a sudden movement(shake or jump) of UIWebview  in viewcontroller** .Is there any way to to this refresh in background i mean without any change in webview movement?

Comment: Just add it to a button action.

Comment: i wanna do at loading time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You van do the same refresh functionality as a background thread,So it will work.